# Invalid rectstyle object

Tags: python, object, pygame

I am following a [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/XGf2GcyHPhc?t=16003) and cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong. I tried it multiple times while changing the value of the rect to no avail.

```
import pygame

width = 500
height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

clientNumber = 0

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = (x,y,width,height)
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += self.vel


def redrawWindow(win, player):
    win.fill(255, 255, 255)
    player.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()



def main():
    run = True
    p = Player(50, 50, 100, 100, (0, 255, 0))
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
        p.move()
        redrawWindow(win, p)

main()
```

I copied the tutorial down to a T but it is a quite old video so I don't know if it is a change to the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot a set of parentheses for your "win.fill()" function.  Instead of:

```
win.fill(255, 255, 255)
```

the program needs:

```
win.fill((255, 255, 255))
```

That function is actually wanting a single three-color tuple value.

When I made that change, the window appeared.

[image: Game Window]